# Set Date object in JSON request object to server using Postman

Tags: json, date, postman, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a web service that I want to test.I am checking it with the help of Postman. I am facing issues when I have to set the date object in the JSON.

Here is my User class:
P.S: I am using Flask-sqlalchemy to create the database models.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(60), nullable=True, default=None)
    username = db.Column('user_name', db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    dob = db.Column('date_of_birth', db.Date, nullable=True, default=None)
```

And here is my JSON data that I am trying to post to the 'register' route - `http://127.0.0.1:5000/register`

```
{
    "name": "Catherin Francisco",
    "username": "c_francisco",
    "dob": new Date("1988-06-27")
}
```

I am getting `400 Bad Request: Failed to decode JSON object` while setting the 'dob' key-value pair. 
Can anyone please help me to set up the date object in JSON.

Comment: You're doing this in the pre-request script section? body? What's actually been sent out?

Comment: body=>raw data=>json

Comment: You have to write date as iso date string like `2020-02-04T10:58:49.024Z`. Because javascript date object won't work at body unless you write it at prescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is set the date in the `pre-request` script section and set the value in a variable. For example:

```
var timestamp = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ");
pm.environment.set("timestamp", timestamp);
```

Then in the `body` of your request you can use it simply with `{{timestamp}}`

```
{
  "name": "Catherin Francisco",
  "username": "c_francisco",
  "dob": "{{timestamp}}"
}
```

Comment: I have an error: There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You should also add it at the very top of the `pre-request` script to avoid errors with `moment`:

```
const moment = require('moment');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).